# c# test bandwidth between server and client applications

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, timeout, bandwidth

I am new to programming. For my first application I decided to create two console applications - server and client application. I want to test data transaction bandwith between client and server app(by the way I am using sockets). The problem I have is that I need to test connection speed for, lets say 10 seconds and after those 10 seconds I need to get received data amount (which I have received in this time period) and calculate speed...How can I do that?

**Client app**

```
namespace Example_01_Sockets_Client
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            var ownAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            var ownEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ownAddress, 4321);

            socket.Bind(ownEndpoint);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Trying to connect to server...");
            var serverAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            socket.Connect(serverAddress, 2222);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to server");

            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 150000];
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 100;

            int receivedBytesLen = socket.Receive(buffer);

            Console.WriteLine("Download speed: " + ((receivedBytesLen) / 100 + "kb/s ") );

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
            socket.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Server App**

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool exit = false;

        while (!exit)
        {
            var listeningSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 2222);

            listeningSocket.Bind(localEndpoint);
            listeningSocket.Listen(1);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client...");
            Socket connectedSocket = listeningSocket.Accept();
            listeningSocket.Close();
            string clientAddress = connectedSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected (" + clientAddress + ")");

            string fileName = "downTest.txt";
            byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);

            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
            byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
            byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);

            fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
            fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);

            connectedSocket.Send(fileData);

            //int bytesReceived = connectedSocket.Receive();

            Console.WriteLine("Client connected (" + clientAddress + ")");

            connectedSocket.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a set amount of data (eg. 4,096kb).  Use the Stopwatch class to start a timer right before you start downloading data on the client, and then stop the timer immediately after it finishes sending.  You can then use the elapsed time property to determine how long it took to send that fixed amount of data.

```
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            timer.Start();

            // Download data here

            timer.Stop();

            int elapsedTime = timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about it, that would be a easiest solution.But I want to know is there a possibility to test connection for set period of time? for example I have 4kb large file and if I have 400mbit/s download speed - download will run to fast. But for example if I have 500mb large file and 1mbit/s fast connection -> it will take ages to run the test )))

Comment: Do a small sample (a few megabytes) and get a rough speed.  Then adjust the size of the actual test based on that.  Sending a GB of data over the wire to test a fast connection probably isn't prudent in any scenario, so another solution would be to come up with a good "middle ground" size. 

Using the socket timeout isn't a good solution because that will cause an exception when the timeout occurs, and you'll have no idea how much data was received.

Finally, all of these buffers mean loading data into memory.  If you try to send/receive too much, you'll be testing Disk I/O.

Comment: I would also suggest to make a small , but still quite relevant sized transfer frequently - and instead of running the test once only per interval, make iterations - use the average value als result for this test iteration. If you use this to adjust your applications (like some sort of limiting/delimiting based on bandwith), you can also work with the averages of tests happened within timespan x - and use min/max results as limit for limiting/delimiting.
A few MB sounds totally fine, not large enough to block long time , but still enough to get a good value.